# Lower temperature with 10°C difference: Toshiba Q Series 256 GB vs Samsung 840 Pro 256 GB?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, temperature

(concerning a Gaming Laptop such as the Asus G75VX or G750)

I am thinking of buying Toshiba Q Series 256 GB instead of the Samsung 840 Pro 256 GB as I read on [ssdreview](http://www.ssdreview.com/review/compare/samsung-serie-840-pro-256gb-25-inch-dxm03b0q,toshiba-q-series-256gb-25-inch-htran101/power_consumption.html) that the Toshiba SSD uses less electricity and is 10°C cooler than the Samsung one. My idea was to reduce the overall temperature of the laptop, so that the surface is cooler (when writing large texts). Does this make sense or is this approach unnecessary? Or is the 840 EVO 250 GB the better solution?

Comment: Its very unlikely a different SSD is going to decrease the overal temperature of your CPU by more then a single degree if that.

Comment: if the drive sits right under your palm while typing, then it _may_ make a difference. Why not get an external keyboard for those long typing jaunts?  Much cheaper.  Otherwise, this seems like not much more than a product recommendation request to me.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this make sense or is this approach unnecessary?

It's very unlikely a different SSD is going to decrease the overall temperature of your laptop by more then a single degree if that.

Your not going to be able to cool the overall system with a SSD that is only 10 degrees cooler.